# EJML obtain matrix eigenvectors' real value

Tags: java, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvector, ejml

I am trying to make a conversion from a non positive definite matrix into a positive definite one in order to be able to make a *cholesky* decomposition. Working with *EJML*, which I think is a good library, I have come into a trouble when trying to obtain the *eigenvectors* of a matrix.

*EJML* returns a null value for each *eigenvector* where exists an imaginary value. It does not offer any functionality (not an obvious one, at least) to extract the real value, unlike other *java* libraries like *JBlas*.

According to *EJML* *javadoc* ([here](http://efficient-java-matrix-library.googlecode.com/svn-history/r307/javadoc/ver0.17/org/ejml/alg/dense/decomposition/EigenDecomposition.html#getEigenVector(int))):

> MatrixType **getEigenVector**(int index)

Used to retrieve real valued eigenvectors. If an eigenvector is associated with a complex eigenvalue then null is returned instead.

*Parameters:*

> index - Index of the eigenvalue eigenvector pair.

*Returns:*

> If the associated eigenvalue is real then an eigenvector is returned, null otherwise.

In order to reproduce my issue, consider the following algorithm:

```
DenseMatrix64F origMatrix = RandomMatrices.createRandom(size, size, -2, 2, rand);

Original Matrix (non positive definite):

0.543  -1.405   1.580  
1.227   1.686  -0.064  
1.080  -1.689   0.645 

EigenDecomposition<DenseMatrix64F> eig = DecompositionFactory.eig(size, true);
eig.decompose(origMatrix);

int eigValNum = eig.getNumberOfEigenvalues();  

for(int i = 0; i < eigValNum; i++){
    DenseMatrix64F eigMat = eig.getEigenVector(i);
    if(eigMat != null){
        //Store all vectors inside a matrix
    }
}

Eigenvector Matrix:

0.000   0.000   0.573  
0.000   0.000  -0.299  
0.000   0.000  -0.763
```

For what I understand, the first two columns on *eigenvectors* matrix are null due to an existent imaginary value which makes *EJML* return a NULL value. I need a method or technique that will allow me to margin the imaginary values and extract the real ones without loosing all the vector in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJML doesn't support complex eigenvectors.  To compute complex eigenvectors support for complex matrices and a complex eigenvalue decomposition must be provided, which EJML doesn't provide.  You could make a feature request on its website.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it could be as easy as checking myself the availability of complex matrices. I hope your answer will help others sometime in the future.

Comment: Although still unsupported, the author of the library states that it could add complex matrix support sooner than later. Source: http://goo.gl/3uf1RW